# Running gulp exec based on condition

Tags: ionic-framework, gulp, exec

I am working on ionic project integrated with gulp. How can run `exec` command based on condition?

I have tried following

```
    var isIOSBuild = false;
    if(args.iosBuild){
      isIOSBuild = true;
      console.log("Creating IOS Build...");
    }
    // Build application
    gulp.task('ios_build', function (cb) {
        gulp.src('', {read: false})
        .pipe(gulpif(false,
          exec(IOS_BUILD_COMMAND,
            {
                cwd : './',
                maxBuffer: 1024 * 1024
            },
            function (err, stdout, stderr) {
                console.log(stdout);
                console.log(stderr);
                cb(err);
            })
        ));
    });
```

**Input**: `gulp -r`

I have put up condition for running **`exec command`** still the **IOS_BUILD_COMMAND** is running. Unable to understand why this is happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can call the gulp task with or without arguments and run the task internally on the argument condition.

I use [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) to make my life easier.

```
var args = require('yargs').argv;

gulp.task('some_task', function(){
   if(args.condition){
     // run your task
   }
})
```

Call gulp like so: `gulp some_task --condition=true` or `gulp some_task --condition=false`

That allows you to maintain the condition outside of gulp